# Where is the "Office for Foreign Aliens" in Siem Reap, Cambodia?

Tags: visa-extensions, cambodia, locate-this, siem-reap

I'm currently in Siem Reap, Cambodia with six days validity left on my visa and I've decided to pay the $45 for an extension since I like it here and since with the weekend starting and then Tet starting in Vietnam with a slew of public holidays I probably can't get a Vietnam visa in time!

Anyway, [the information I find on the web tells me](http://www.cambodiahome.com/cambodiaimmigration.htm) to extend in Siem Reap I must go to the

> Office for Foreign Aliens in Siem Reap town.

But I can't seem to find where that is. Yesterday I thought I found it on Google maps but ended up in some bizarre half-dead failed development area between the town and the archeological park!

So yes I can ask at my guesthouse, but for the benefit of other people on the interwebs I'll ask in a post here. **Where is this "Office for Foreign Aliens?** aka **Where do I go to extend my visa in Siem Reap?**

Comment: My understanding is that visas can only be extended in Phnom Penh, but you don't need to be physically present so travel agencies are happy to proxy them for you.  Happy to be proved wrong though!

Comment: Yes I've heard travel agencies will do it but I'd spend my food and accommodation money on that only if I do have to go to PP and run out of time. Either way it's good to know if sites like the one I quoted are full of inaccuracies \-:

Comment: Have to agree with jpatokal, the only place I know of where you can extend a tourist visa is in Phnom Penh at the Immigration Office across from the airport.  And only one extension allowed.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It looks like that page I quoted on `www.cambodiahome.com` is at least out of date, and probably just outright wrong.

I asked the person at the desk at my guesthouse and it seems [jpatokal](https://travel.stackexchange.com/users/1893/jpatokal) and [Tom](https://travel.stackexchange.com/users/13044/tom) are right that it can't be done directly in Siem Reap.

The guesthouse quoted me a price above $60 taking four days by sending it off to Phnom Penh.

I think I'll head for the capital tomorrow and try to get the extension on Monday at the office in the airport.

Comment: $60 on top of the $45 fee? or including it?

Comment: @MeNoTalk: That was including everything, but the $45 apparently also already includes a fee! I think I found that it's $35 if you do it yourself at the office in the PP airport. I suppose I could ask yet another question about that ...